# NoReverseMatch at /<urls>

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using django 1.10. I want to know how the reverse function works. This is a basic chat application using django. I am stuck at line no:7 in `index.html`
Below ones are the files:

[image]

viwes.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from chat.models import ChatRoom

def index(request):
    chat_rooms= ChatRoom.objects.order_by('name')[:5]
    context = {
        'chat_list' : chat_rooms
    }
    return render(request,'chats/index.html', context)


def chat_room(request,chat_room_id):
    chat = get_object_or_404(ChatRoom, pk =chat_room_id)
    return render(request,'chats/chat_room.html', {'chat':chat})
```

chat/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import reverse

from chat import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<chat_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.chat_room, name='chat_room'),
]
```

index.html

```
{% if chat_list %}</pre>
<ul>
    <ul>{% for chat in chat_list %}</ul>
</ul>
<ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="" href="{% url 'chat_room' chat.id %}"> {{ chat.name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
<ul>{% endfor %}</ul>
<pre>



{% else %}

No chats are available.

{% endif %}
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: please, add full error stack

Comment: Which `url` you tried ? If you run this in `localhost` then `127.0.0.1:8000` should be your index and `127.0.0.1:8000/id` should be your chat room. `id` should be any numeric number. No other `url` is defined. Make sure you entered correct `url`.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/chats/

Comment: I added full error stack at first @BearBrown. Please do help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i can see in your reeal code you have a typo:

```
 {% url 'chat_room' chat_room_id %}
                  <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

but in the question you write correct

```
{% url 'chat_room' chat.id %}
```

just apply it to your code

Comment: can you tell me why it is chat.id?

Comment: in your loop `chat` it is an instance of your model `ChatRoom` so you need to use the `id`

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation!